# Check what $(this) is

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get an alert for each but one checkbox that is clicked.

This is my JS code:

```
 $('#acts').find(':checkbox').click(function(){
     if($(this) == 'all')
     {
         alert('Checkbox Clicked');
     }
 });
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="acts">
    <input type="checkbox" id="all">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Brussel" name="locality"> <label>Brussel</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Anderlecht" name="locality"> <label>Anderlecht</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Oudergem" name="locality"> <label>Oudergem</label>
</div>
```

I tried this first this way, but also tried adding

```
var theName = $(this);
```

and

```
var theName = String($(this));
```

and compare in the IF statement agains 'theName', but $(this) or the variable that I assign it to, keeps returning me [Object][object], against which I can't compare just like that.

Comment: Did you mean `this.id == 'all'`?

Comment: that's because $(this) is an object representing the current checkbox not a string id!

Comment: Good advice: use a checkbox' `change` event, not `click`. Some browsers fire click event before actually changing the value, and presumably you only want to fire the event *after the checkbox value has been altered due to clicking on it*. I forget which browser has which event order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply check

```
if(this.id == 'all')
```

Note that for accessing the `id` property there is **no need** to do `$(this).attr('id')`: it is quicker to access the property directly.

As @RoryMcCrossan says in the comment below, `this` and `$(this)` are **objects** so it makes no sense comparing them to a **string**.

Comment: Just to add, any `$()` operation returns a jQuery object, therefore the comparison to a string in the OP will never work. You need to compare to a specific property of the object, as this answer is doing.

Comment: Ok, this seems to work just fine :-) However, I tried $(this).id() == 'all' before, but that failed...

Comment: That fails 'cause you try to call a non-existent method `id`

Comment: And why doesn't $(this).id == 'all' work (Forgive me my stupid question)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17970451/301596 once you wrap it in jquery its attributes changes, you then have to access it with jquery functions like attr or prop

Comment: Right, * this * is the JavaScript object, * $(this) * is the jQuery object?

Answer (score 5):

Like this.

```
$(this).attr("id") == 'all'
```

Although using "id" to "recognize" an element is not quite the best way to do it. Remember you can only have one id on a page. `data` attr would be probably more appropriate way of doing this. In which case you'd do

```
<input type="checkbox" data-something="all" />

$(this).data("something") == 'all';
```

Comment: `id` is a property so `.prop()` would be more appropriate if jQuery must be used.

Comment: Depends on version of jquery `.prop()` was added more recently.

Comment: That's more than two years ago :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out more about each object, try:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify($(this)));
```

Comment: Simple `console.log($(this));` would do as well.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe that would simply give him "[Object][object]".

Comment: Yea you are wrong indeed. `alert()` would give him "[Object][object]", console.log would work just fine.

Comment: Thought I may have been.